# Should yes/no columns in a table be aligned left or right?

Tags: user-expectation, tables

I understand the guidance on positioning text and numeric columns. I also have a column, though, that presents a boolean (Y/N) value. Is it appropriate to align it to the left as text, or right as numeric?

Comment: I'd rather make it a check mark and align center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to be concerned about alignment of Y and N. Better to make the column fit it's content and center the text. Or use a symbol like Harshal said in the comment. See for example:

[image]

The column header should be short to avoid getting to much white space. If this isn't possible the alignment of Y/N should be the same as the header. 
So it should be either the first or the last column:

[image]

If the text length is variable, see the following example: Which column is easier to scan?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that the alignment is the most important element in your column of yes and no. The most important is helping the people to scan easier the column.

- Y or N are easier to scan than Yes and No.
- Since there are only 2 options, I would really consider using Y only or N only, as you can see in the image below.
- Color marking might be a good option
- As well, a switch could be easeful, especially if your user is able to change the value in column.

[image: Different ways]

Comment: In my experience, some people interpret an empty cell as undefined or as an error. Always set a value to communicate at least something.